# Running npm command from expressjs?

Tags: npm, express, node-modules

Can i run something like: `npm install passport` from expressjs itself?

I want to check if i'm using a non installed module and install it before running the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, you should be able to check the FileSystem for specific files/folders using [fs](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). I imagine you would need to parse your package.json and check the local node_modules or the global install path.

I would recommend a shell script to `run npm install` and then fire up your app from within the same script.

```
npm install .
node <server> &
```

Comment: how can i run shell script from express?

Comment: So based on your question, my assumption is, there is only one app you want to ensure sure have it's modules installed, and it's the app built on express, no? So, in this case, you would write a simple shell script that will be used to start your app. This script would be executed outside of express. If this is not the case, please clarify the situation.

Comment: Yes this is the case. I was asking how to execute a shell command from express, but i found how.